# How to pass the Header while calling the Apollo Query?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo, apollostack

I'm trying to pass the token inside the header while calling the apollo query for graphql inside the vue application. But this is not working. I don't want to add header inside the main.js as we need to store it inside the localstorage of the browser. I searched and got to know that we can do like this. What I am doing wrong here ?
this.$apollo.query( {
query: gql `query getuser { Username { Username }}`,

```
               variables: {
                },
                    context:{
                        header:{
                            Authorization: this.token ? `Bearer ${this.token}` : ''
                      
                        },
                                                  },
  }).then((data) => {

      alert("Inside  Query...");

      }
        */
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('error in creating order: ', error);
      alert('error in creating order: ' + error);
  });

},
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `header` to `headers`?

```js
context: {
    headers: { // Instead of header
        Authorization: this.token ? `Bearer ${this.token}` : ''
    },
},
```